# Estilizar o player nativo de video HTML5

Tags: html5, css3

Há alguma maneira de estilizar o player nativo de video do HTML5? Se sim, como?
Obs:Não crio o meu propio player pois é somente uma alteração básica.

Comment: Você provavelmente pode modificar alguma coisa básica via CSS (não é minha área), mas se você realmente quiser modificar, é necessário utilizar outros elementos HTML/JS para criar um player customizado.

Comment: Cara normalmente cada Browser tem o seu estilo "css" de player, aqui vc pode ver uma imagem https://www.htmlgoodies.com/imagesvr_ce/3437/Image1.png se vc não for mais claro no que vc precisa fica complicado te responder. Se possível coloque uma imagem ou explique melhor o que precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, existem maneiras de estilizar o player de video/midia do HTML5. Você usa CSS e JavaScript para isso.

Eu não conseguiria fazer um exemplo funcional disso de imediato, mas tem esse exemplo [aqui](https://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player/) para você dar uma olhada.

Segundo o link, você pode criar algumas funções bem simples em JavaScript/JQuery para poder editar o player apenas com CSS, elas são:

```
$('#seuvideo')[0].play(); // Iniciar visualização do video
$('#seuvideo')[0].pause(); // Pausar visualização
$('#seuvideo')[0].volume = 1; // Define o volume, valor deve ser entre 0 e 1.
$('#seuvideo')[0].currentTime; // Momento atual do video
$('#seuvideo')[0].duration; // Duração do video
$('#seuvideo')[0].buffered; // Quanto tempo, em segundos, que seu video está bufferizado
if($('#seuvideo')[0].canPlayType('video/mp4')) { ... // Se o video pode ser visto com esse formato
$('#seuvideo')[0].requestFullscreen; // (experimental) deixa o video ocupando a tela toda do computador.
```

Agora o CSS, você edita as classes player (`.player`) e video (`.video`). Você pode usar também as entradas `.video:hover .player`, `.player .progress`, `.player .progress-bar`, `.player .button-holder`, `.player .progress-button`, `.player [class^="buffered"]`, `.player .play-pause`, `.player .play, .player .pause-button`, `.player .play .pause-button, .player .pause .play-button`, `.player .pause-button`, `.player .pause-button span`, `.player .pause-button span:first-of-type`, `.player .time`, `.player .stime .ttime`, `.player .play:hover`, `.player .play:active, .pause-button:active span`, `.player .pause-button:hover span`, `.player .volume`, `.player .volume-icon`, `.player .volume-icon-hover`, `.player .volume-holder`, `.player .valume-bar-holder`, `.player .volume-button`, `.player .volume-button-holder`, `.pplayer .volume-bar`, `.player .fullscreen`, `.player .fullscreen a`, `.player .volume-icon span`, `.player .volume-icon span:before, .player .volume-icon span:after`, `.player .volume-icon span:before`, `.player .volume-icon span:after` e as classes `.player .v-change-X span:after` onde X varia de 1 a 11 (ambos inclusos).

Existem ainda mais funções para fazer no jQuery.